# Get output in exit codes

Tags: python

```
import sys

List = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

if 'c' in List: 
    sys.exit(0) 
else:    
    sys.exit(1)
```

I want to print output as `O` or `1` codes. But, I don't get any output.

Comment: Use `exit` to exit the script.  Use `print` to print data.

Comment: Can't we print codes 0 or 1 ??

Comment: Yes; `print(0)`

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, immediately after running the program, type:

```
echo $?
```

On Windows, in a `cmd` shell, execute the python program and immediately after type:

```
echo %errorlevel%
```

Comment: Im using Linux, not working ... do I have to add something in script too?

Comment: Nice. One liner for windows would be `python my_script.py & echo %errorlevel%`.

Comment: @Kiran fixed... and I see another user posted also

Comment: Hey, but I want something directly from script. Can we do that ?

Comment: You can print whatever you want to the console, such as an error message. I'm not sure what you mean if something else.

Comment: I mean I want either exit(0) or exit(1) in output. when I run myprogram.py

Comment: So print that before exiting.

Answer (score 1):

A naive solution on `bash` would be to check the exit status of the last program you've run, like this:

```
$ python foo.py
$ echo $?
```

Comment: How can I get this directly from script ?

Comment: You can add some `print` functions before calling `sys.exit()`. Remember that when you call `exit` the 'control' goes back to the shell, so it has to be the last instruction you want to execute inside your script.